# Can't locate autovivification.pm in @INC

Tags: perl, perl-module, cpan, autovivification

I get the following error when I run my Perl script:

> "Can't locate autovivification.pm in @INC"

How can I install this module on my system?

Answer (score 2):

You need to download the [autovivification module](http://search.cpan.org/dist/autovivification/) from [CPAN](http://www.cpan.org) and [install it](http://www.cpan.org/modules/INSTALL.html).

Comment: It is generally a good idea to link to the version agnostic url `http://search.cpan.org/dist/autovivification/` or `https://metacpan.org/release/autovivification`

Comment: @BradGilbert: Good point. Fixed.